# Create Custom Attributes for SAML in Azure

Tags: azure, saml, custom-attributes

I have a custom application for which I am setting up single sign on using Azure Active Directory. I created application in Azure and configured single sign on. I used Azure metadata in my application and could login successfully using single sign on.

Now I have a requirement to send custom attributes from Azure to my application through SAML. How do I do it?

Comments in Link [Customizing Attributes](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-saas-customizing-attribute-mappings/#comments) says it is not possible. Setting up B2C as per link [B2C Custome Attributes](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr/) doesn't give me any option of single sign on or metadata.

How do I go about it?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm seriously pulling my hair out with Azure AD and SAML... EVERY other provider allows custom claims, but I can't see any easy way to do it in Azure.